# Selecting Multiple Cells on a KendoGrid in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a scenario where a user is able to select multiple cells on a grid. I would like to validate the users selection and deselect any invalid cells. I am trying to achieve this in the change function on my grid. My current approach is to get the currently selected cells, determine which cells are valid and select the list of valid cells I have found.

According to Kendo's documentation, the grid.select() function does take a parameter, but only takes an array of rows as a parameter. This explains why the below isnt working.

I need a solution which allows me to set which cells are highlighted and also retrieve the highlighted cells (I currently can get selected cells via the grid.select() method).

Is there a reasonable way to do this?

```
$scope.myKendoGridOptions = {
        selectable: "multiple, cell",
        change: function (e) {
            if (!$scope.jsSelectChangeEvent) {
                var grid = $('#myKendoGrid').data("kendoGrid");
                var selectedItems = grid.select();

                if (selectedItems.length > 1) {
                    var validItems = [];
                    var validRowIndex = selectedItems[0].closest("tr").rowIndex;

                    for (var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
                        if (selectedItems[i].closest("tr").rowIndex === validRowIndex) {
                            validItems.push(selectedItems[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    //Avoids Infinite loop
                    $scope.jsSelectChangeEvent = true;
                    //im expecting this to select my valid cells, but it has no effect
                    grid.select(validItems);
                }
            } else {
                $scope.jsSelectChangeEvent = false;
            }

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grid.select(validItems) does accept cells as a parameter. The problem is that I need to call grid.clearSelect() prior to calling grid.select to get the desired effect.